# php get string from binary file

Tags: php, file, binaryfiles, strpos

I have JPG image with XMP meta data inside.
I'd like to read this data, but how?

```
$content = file_get_contents($fileName);
var_dump($content);
```

displays real number of bytes `553700`
but

```
$len = strlen($content);
var_dump($len);
```

displays `373821`

So, I can't simple do

```
$xmpStart = strpos($content, '<x:xmpmeta');
```

because I get wrong offset.
So, the question is, how to find and read string from binary file in PHP?
(I have mb_string option `ON` in php.ini)

**UPD1:**

I have some binary file. How can I check in PHP, this file contains several strings or not?

Comment: Ah, it's clearer now. Essentially, it shouldn't matter what kind of data is being used.  Can you try whether `strlen($content, "iso-8859-1")`  gives the correct value?

Comment: `$pos = strpos($content, '<x:xmpmeta', 0, 'iso-8859-1');` now it pointers to right offset. Thanks. But how can I know about last `encoding` parameter? :) There is no information about this in http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php huh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, it doesn't matter what kind of data you are reading - `strlen()` et al. should always work.

What I think is happening here is that on your server, `strlen()` is internally overridden by [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) and the internal character encoding is set to UTF-8.

UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding, so some of the characters in your (wildly arbitrary) byte stream get interpreated as multi-byte characters - resulting in a shortened length of `373821` instead of `553700`.

I can't think of a better workaround than always explicitly specifying a single-byte encoding like `iso-8859-1`:

```
 $pos = strpos($content, '<x:xmpmeta', 0, 'iso-8859-1');
```

this forces `strpos()` (or rather, `mb_strpos()`) to count every single byte in the data.

This will always work; I do not know whether there is a more elegant way to force the use of a  single-byte encoding.

Answer (score 1):

[Getid3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) is a PHP package that claims to be able to read XMP Metadata.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It can help, but if I have to read own strings from binary files? How can it be done?

Comment: @Lari you'd have to build your own JPG parser. While surely very interesting, it's likely to be  a huge task.

Comment: Let's forget JPG. :) I have some binary file. How can I check in PHP, this file contains several strings or not?

Answer (score 0):

The exif_read_data() PHP function could help the XMP meta data

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php